# Mule Cache Scope Error com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException

Tags: mule, mule-cluster

I am using Mule Cache scope to save JSON data (converted to string) retrieved from a REST call. All works fine locally but when deployed to the server which is clustered I get this error.

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN

Not sure why it is trying to serialize rabbitmq channelN.

Answer (score 0):

When cache scope includes any Rest calls (i.e HTTP Request configurations) , make sure you have Dataweave or Byte array to String or Object to String to make it as consumable payload. Because HTTP request configuration output will be "grizzly Bufferinputstream" which is not consumable payload and its not serializable